# how to select some columns with null or empty rows

Tags: sql, select, plsql

I have a table with 5 columns in each row, I want to select * when status column =1 and see just date and status columns if it is not =1

[image]

Comment: if column status is not equal to one then do you want to show only two columns? did you pass any parameter?

Comment: This is something which would probably be best handled in your presentation layer, rather than in pure SQL.  A SQL query returns the same number of columns for every record, not different number of columns.

Comment: if column is not equal to 1 then i want to show all columns but except date and stat. columns are null

Comment: like this you can do `select * from YourTable where status = 1
union all
select date,status,'' asd,'' asd, '' asd, '' asd,'' ads from YourTable where status != 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is better, because the union makes the query run very slow.

```
SELECT date,
    status,
    CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN asd end as asd,
    CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN asd1 end as asd1,
 ...
FROM table
```

Comment: You can add in the case statement `ELSE` like: `CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN asd ELSE '' END AS asd`